# Real analysis: if a function is differentiable does it imply that it has a power series?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I would like to know if there is an analogous proof to that in complex analysis where one proves that if a function is holomorphic it is also analytic (i.e.) power series exists but for real analysis.

Moreover, for any real differentiable function can I take the analytic continuation and define it on a complex set (which includes the real numbers) to so that it is holomorphic and with which to show that it is hence analytic and that power series exist at every point (hence on the real line too)?

Comment: A standard counter-example is $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Hi @KaviRamaMurthy , am I wrong in thinking this function is not differentiable at 0?

Comment: It should be -1/x^2 in the exponent. Then the function is infinitely differentiable at 0

Comment: @NathanLowry My function does work and it is standard example. You don't need $x^{2}$. Another example would be $e^{-1/x^{2}}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I have only seen the example with the $x^2$, so I must have thought it was necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Although in complex analysis being holomorphic and analytic are equivalent notions, the same is not true in real analysis. Consider the example
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x},&x>0\\0,&x\leq0\end{cases}$$
defined on $\mathbb R$. It can be shown that this function is not only differentiable, but in fact infinitely differentiable at every point of the real line, including $x=0$. Nevertheless, it is not analytic at $0$: all of its derivatives evaluate to $0$ at $x=0$, so its Taylor series there is $0$, and thus does not agree with the function for $x>0$. You can read more about this [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function).

You can intuitively think about the above example like this: the function $e^{-1/x}$ decreases incredibly rapidly as $x\to0^+$ since $1/x$ blows up to $+\infty$, so that near $0^+$ all the information about the function at $x>0$ is crushed by the rapid decrease. (This is obviously not rigorous.) Thus at $x=0$, it locally appears to be exactly like the zero function, and so its Taylor series there, which can only access local information, is the zero function, despite the function not being identically zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the asnwer! I just have a quick question, if we were to define $f(z)$ for the complex plane in the same manner but for $|z|> 0$ and for $|z|=0$ how would you know it is not holomorphic (I mean without looking at the fact that is not analytic)?

Comment: @MathsWizzard somewhat surprisingly, the function is holomorphic at $0$. However, it is not holomorphic anywhere else: considering the limit definition, you can show that taking the limit by approaching any point $z_0\neq0$ along the radial and tangential directions (aka by fixing $\theta$ and changing $r$, or the other way around) will give you nonzero and zero values for the limit respectively. Since complex limits must agree regardless of which direction you approach in, this shows that the derivative doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @YiFan, I did some further reading. The complex function that I defined in my comment is in fact not well defined at 0 and hence not holomorphic at zero. Everything else in the real scenario should be fine though.

Comment: @MathsWizzard it is well defined, actually, since you give it a value there. I presume you were referring to the function $$f(z):=\begin{cases}e^{-1/|z|},&z\neq0\\0,&z=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: No sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I was referring to $$ f(z) =\begin{cases} 
      e^{- \frac{1}{z}} & |z|> 0 \\
      0 & |z|=0
   \end{cases} $$

Comment: @MathsWizzard Oh, I see. That function is still well defined at $0$ since you explicitly gave it a value there, but you're correct that it's not holomorphic at $0$.

Comment: Hi, are you sure it is well defined? Approaching the limit from the negative real axis gives it a different value.

Comment: @MathsWizzard That makes the function *discontinuous*, which is a different thing. Being well defined just means that the function takes a single, defined value at $x=0$ (in this case, defined to be $0$), so for instance the real function given by $f(x)=1$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is also well defined, even though clearly discontinuous.

Comment: A quick question doesn't discontinuity imply that the function is not holomorphic at this point?

Comment: @MathsWizzard Yup, of course! So you're correct that the function isn't holomorphic at $0$ (my first comment above was referring to the different function where I misunderstood your first comment). I was just saying that the function is well defined at $0$, even though not holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact, even being infinitely differentiable is not sufficient: for example, define the following function:

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2^k}}\cos\left(2^kx\right).$$

This series, and each of the series $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d^n}}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\left(e^{-\sqrt{2^k}}\cos\left(2^kx\right)\right)$$ (which are just the same series multiplied by some power of $2^k$, with $\cos$ cyclically replaced by $-\sin$, $-\cos$, $\sin$, $\cos$, etc.) is absolutely and uniformly convergent by the Weierstrass M-test, and so $f$ is $C^\infty$: that is, at every point, we can differentiate $f$ as many times as we like.

However, if we take $x = \frac{n\pi}{2^k}$, and $m > k$, we have
$$f^{(2^m)}(x) = \sum\limits_{i=m+1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2^i}}2^{2^mi} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m e^{-\sqrt{2^i}}2^{2^mi}\cos(2^ix).$$ Now, we need to do some bounding. That first part is bounded below by $$e^{-\sqrt{2^{2m+2}}}2^{2^{m+1}(m+1)},$$ and the second part is bounded in absolute value by something $O(2^{kn})$, so we have $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{f^{(2^m)}(x)}{(2^m)!}\right)^{1/2^m} =+\infty,$$ and hence $$\limsup_{j \to \infty}\left(\frac{f^{(j)}}{j!}\right)^{1/j} = +\infty.$$
The Cauchy-Hadamard formula then implies that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series for $f$ at all such $x$ is $0$, so $f$ cannot be analytic at any such $x$. But also, domains of analyticity are open, and the set of all such points $x$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so $f$ is nowhere analytic.