# Proving $e^{ - \frac{1}{x}}$ is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

In a [diffierent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864709/real-analysis-if-a-function-is-differentiable-does-it-imply-that-it-has-a-power) I asked, in the discussion of the answer it was said to me that $$ f(z) =\begin{cases} 
      e^{- \frac{1}{z}} & |z|> 0 \\
      0 & |z|=0
   \end{cases} $$
is holomorphic only at the origin and to prove that it is not holomorphic at a point $z_0 \neq 0$ one has to approach it radially and tangentially to show the limits do not agree.  I struggle to understand what was said to me and how I can algebraically do it. Does this mean that one of the limits has to be taken along the complex line passing through the origin and $z_o$ and the other has to be taken along the tangent to the circle centred at the origin of radius $|z_0|$? And if yes, how can I possibly approach this algebraically? I tried but I struggled to isolate the real and imaginary parts. If anybody can help with the algebra and approach in this, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: This $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: I think $e^{-1/z}$ is holomorphic everywhere except $z=0$.  It is the composition of two holomorphic functions.

Comment: This function is holomorphic on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ except at the origin.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for your comment, why is then $f$ not holomorphic and does this imply that what was said to me is wrong?

Comment: Maybe in that other question you said "in the same manner" but YiFan misunderstood what you meant by that.

Comment: This complex function is not even continuous at $z=0$.  See what happens when $z \to 0$ along the negative real axis.

Comment: @GEdgar ahh this explains why it is not holomorphic. Thank you very much for that. I just wanted to quickly ask, if I was to prove that a function is not holomorphic by showing that limits do not agree to a point $z_0$ do I write $f'(z_0)= u'(x_0, y_0) + iv'(x_0,y_0)$ and then approach this parametrically?

Comment: I would not write $u'$ for a function of two variables.

Comment: @GEdgar could you elaborate on how would you approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $|f( \frac{1}{it})|=1$ for all $t \in \mathbb R.$ Hence $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Consequence: $f$ is not complex differentiable at $0$.

In each $z \ne 0 $ the function $f$ is complex differentiable.